# How to enable Macros on Excel. All tutorials are failing me

Tags: excel, vba

I've tried all possible solutions to enable Macros en Excel files I've used 100s of times, but suddenly MS decided to block them, and I can't use them.

[image]

[image]

I tied all MS instructions:

1. Marked the location where my file is saves as safe in Trust Center -> Trusted Locations.
2. "Enable VBA macros" in Trust Center -> Macro Settings.
3. Tried marking the individual file as "Unblock" under Properties, but this option doesn't exist for me.

Comment: Has IT put a global control on?

Answer (score 0):

*Not Really an Answer, apparently I can't comment*

Are you saving your files as `.xlsm`? If you're saving them as `.xlsx` then it will remove any VBA script you had added.

Or is your Excel just not allowing you to add VBA script at all?

If the latter, then the only thing I can think is to uninstall/reinstall Office. Other than that, idk of any troubleshooting that could help.

Comment: The files are saved as "Microsoft Excel Macro-Enabled Worksheet (.xlsm)". I doubt that reinstalling Office would solve this, since I observed the same problem on 4 different PCs, all using different MS licenses.